# how to add custom search source in Android google search

Tags: android

how to add custom search source in Android google search

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [android-open-search](http://code.google.com/p/android-open-search/)

Comment: thank you, but I'm afraid this is not the answer i'm looking for. What I want is to add my custom search engine entry into the pre-installed google search box.